# What is the name of the OST playing in Episode 5 of Himouto! Umaru-chan at 10:34?

Tags: music, himouto-umaru-chan

What is the name of the OST playing in Episode 5 of Himouto! Umaru-chan 10 minutes and 34 seconds into the episode?  It also plays at 12:43 of Episode 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song you are looking for is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZSGLjbkyrE). The name is お風呂のすすめ. As stated in the commentaries, it is transliterated as "Ofuro no Susume".

Comment: Note: the title is transliterated "Ofuro no Susume".